# Hive, ordering lines using a variable lag

Tags: sql, hive, window, analytics, lag

I have the following hive table:

```
product |  price
   A    |   100
   B    |   102
   C    |   220
   D    |   240
   E    |   242
   F    |   410
```

For every line I would like to divide the lower price by the current price, if the result is greater than 0.9 I would like to increments a row number. If the result is lower than 0.9 then row number should be 1 for this line, and current price become lower price, then iterate.

Result should look like:

```
product |  price | row_number
   A    |   100  |     1
   B    |   102  |     2
   C    |   220  |     1
   D    |   240  |     2
   E    |   242  |     3
   F    |   410  |     1
```

Because:

```
lower price = 100: product A get 1 as row_number
100/102 >= 0.9: product B get 2 as row_number
100/220 < 0.9: product C get 1 as row_number, lower price = 220
220/240 >= 0.9: product D get 2 as row_number
220/242 >= 0.9: product E get 3 as row_number
220/410 < 0.9: product F get 1 as row_number, lower price = 410
```

I was thinking about creating a temporary_row_number just ordered by price:

```
product |  price | temp_row_number
   A    |   100  |     1
   B    |   102  |     2
   C    |   220  |     3
   D    |   240  |     4
   E    |   242  |     5
   F    |   410  |     6
```

And then:

```
Select
   product,
   price,
   case
     when lag(price,temp_row_number-1,0)/price over() >= 0.9 then lag(price,temp_row_number-1,0)
     else price
   end as test
from my_table
```

This will retrieve:

```
product |  price | test
   A    |   100  | 100
   B    |   102  | 100
   C    |   220  | 220
   D    |   240  | 240
   E    |   242  | 242
   F    |   410  | 410
```

But ideally I would like to retrieve

```
product |  price | test
   A    |   100  | 100
   B    |   102  | 100
   C    |   220  | 220
   D    |   240  | 220
   E    |   242  | 220
   F    |   410  | 410
```

So I could compute row_number row using the row_number() function order by product and price and get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE
AS
(select product,price,(case when price between 100 and 200 then 1
             when price between 200 and 300 then 2 
             when price between 300 and 400 then 3 END ) AS RN

```
         FROM #test)
```

SELECT Product,Price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RN ORDER BY RN) FROM CTE
ORDER BY Product